# My minesweeper program works just fine until I click on the top left tile. Everything looks fine

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to make minesweeper in Python by using tkinter. When the program checks for bombs, it works just fine unless the tile clicked is at 0, 0 (top left), in which case the program always has tileNorth and tileWest True, causing the program to check a variable that doesn't exist. This causes an error and leaves the 0, 0 tile blank. The checking works in every other tile, including corners, just not the top left. This should not be happening.

TLDR:
My minesweeper program works just fine, but it always messes up at 0, 0 and creates an error. I don't understand what's wrong...

The Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 11, in <lambda>
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python/Minesweeper/Minesweeper.py", line 133, in tileClicked
    stringVar_{x}_{y}.set(tileValue)""")
  File "<string>", line 56
    if bomb_-1_-1 == True:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

It mentions bomb_-1_-1 which doesn't exist and can't exist... This is why that one if statement needs to work.

My Code:

```
import random
import tkinter

# Functions

def tileClicked(x, y): # Function is ran when a tile is clicked. The tile is defined by the inputted 'x' and 'y' values.

    exec(f"""

global tileNorth, tileEast, tileSouth, tileWest

if y > 0:
    tileNorth = True

else:
    tileNorth = False

if x < game.size[0] - 1:
    tileEast = True

else:
    tileEast = False

if y < game.size[1] - 1:
    tileSouth = True

else:
    tileSouth = False

if x > 0:
    tileWest = True

else:
    tileWest = False""")

    print(f"""{tileNorth}
{tileEast}
{tileSouth}
{tileWest}
DIV""")

    exec(f"""

print("{x}, {y}")

if bomb_{x}_{y} == True:
    stringVar_{x}_{y}.set("Bomb")
    game.failed = True

if x == 0 and y == 0:
    tileValue = int(0)

    if tileNorth == True:

        if tileEast == True:

            if bomb_{x + 1}_{y - 1} == True:
                tileValue += 1

    if tileEast == True:

        if bomb_{x + 1}_{y} == True:
            tileValue += 1

    if tileSouth == True:

        if tileEast == True:

            if bomb_{x + 1}_{y + 1} == True:
                tileValue += 1

        if tileWest == True:

            if bomb_{x - 1}_{y + 1} == True:
                tileValue += 1

        if bomb_{x}_{y + 1} == True:
            tileValue += 1

    if tileWest == True:

        if bomb_{x - 1}_{y} == True:
            tileValue += 1

else:
    tileValue = int(0)

    if tileNorth == True:

        if tileEast == True:

            if bomb_{x + 1}_{y - 1} == True:
                tileValue += 1

        if tileWest == True:

            if bomb_{x - 1}_{y - 1} == True:
                tileValue += 1

        if bomb_{x}_{y - 1} == True:
            tileValue += 1

    if tileEast == True:

        if bomb_{x + 1}_{y} == True:
            tileValue += 1

    if tileSouth == True:

        if tileEast == True:

            if bomb_{x + 1}_{y + 1} == True:
                tileValue += 1

        if tileWest == True:

            if bomb_{x - 1}_{y + 1} == True:
                tileValue += 1

        if bomb_{x}_{y + 1} == True:
            tileValue += 1

    if tileWest == True:

        if bomb_{x - 1}_{y} == True:
            tileValue += 1

    if tileValue == 0:
        tileValue = "Clear"

    stringVar_{x}_{y}.set(tileValue)""")

# Classes

class game:
    title = "Minesweeper"
    bg = "white"
    fg = "black"
    size = [10, 10]
    tileWidth = 3
    tileHeight = 2
    failed = False
    bombFrequency = 4
    flagMode = False

# Execution

window = tkinter.Tk() # The window.
window.title(game.title)
window.config(bg = game.bg)

mainFrame = tkinter.Frame(window, bg = game.bg) # Main frame that everything is located in.

titleFrame = tkinter.Frame(mainFrame, bg = game.bg) # Title frame.
titleLabel = tkinter.Label(titleFrame, bg = game.bg, fg = game.fg, text = game.title, font = "none 20").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
titleFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

tileFrame = tkinter.Frame(mainFrame, bg = game.bg) # Frame where tiles are located.

x = 0
y = 0

for tiles_x in range(game.size[0]): # Generates tiles.

    for tiles_y in range(game.size[1]):

        exec(f"""global tile_{x}_{y}, stringVar_{x}_{y}, bomb_{x}_{y}
bomb_{x}_{y} = random.randint(1, game.bombFrequency)

if bomb_{x}_{y} == 1:
    bomb_{x}_{y} = True

else:
    bomb_{x}_{y} = False

stringVar_{x}_{y} = tkinter.StringVar(tileFrame)
tile_{x}_{y} = tkinter.Button(tileFrame, bg = 'lightgrey', fg = 'black', width = game.tileWidth, height = game.tileHeight, textvariable = stringVar_{x}_{y}, command = lambda: tileClicked({x}, {y})).grid(row = {y}, column = {x})""")

        y += 1

    x += 1
    y = 0

tileFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

mainFrame.pack() # The main frame is packed so everything is centered.

window.mainloop()
```

I don't care if you think dynamic variables are inefficient, it's my choice. I don't want people to comment on my methods of accomplishing a task... unless it's causing the problem...

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use dynamic variable names, and not lists?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Please read the bottom of the post.

Comment: OK, time for a downvote ;)

Comment: @trincot Because the variables are dynamically created. Please read the bottom of the post.

Comment: @trincot I am here to receive help, not be mocked.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It is? Please tell me why and how I can solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: If you are truly coming for help, then you should not dismiss our help like that. Using dynamic variables is bad practice and is causing you trouble. It is to be fixed. However, if you are not interested in that, and know better, I walk away...

Comment: ...And although you claim things are working perfectly apart from this error on cell 0,0, this cannot be true. Also in other locations on the first row or first column you'll eventually get wrong results because of the same problem. Not an error, but wrong results because of the unintended subtraction.

Comment: @Carcigenicate No I know that, the problem is that negative numbers are being generated when they shouldn't be.

Comment: @trincot Feel free to run the code and see that it doesn't. It's only on tile 0, 0.

Comment: I don't have to. I agree that the *error* is only on cell 0,0, but this `if` condition will perform a subtraction on the first row and first column cells, which obviously is not the intention of the algorithm.

Comment: Just listen to the good advise and get rid of dynamic variables. Do it the right way, with lists.

Comment: @trincot Everything works as intended on every corner cell other than the top left corner. The unintended subtraction is only ever ran on the top left. Also, why IS there an unintended subtraction? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @trincot And while we're on the topic, what's actually wrong with dynamic variables? And how would lists replace them?

Comment: @JoshWalters `if bomb_{x - 1}_{y - 1} == True:` will cause negatives when x and y are 0. You'll need to check the values of x and y prior to subtraction to avoid this issue. And dynamic variables via strings like this are bad because they'll be much slower than just using normal variables, and they prevent you from making use of any functions that are used for sequences. This code could likely be greatly cleaned up by iterating a 2D list with a 2D `for` loop. There are just 0 advantages to use dynamic variables other than the lack of need to learn alternate ways.

Comment: I strongly suggest posting this on [codereview.se] when you're done and have complete working code.

Comment: I'm sure others have said this, but don't use `exec` in this way. There are much better ways to track a dynamic set of values.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the info!

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks, I haven't really seen much about dynamic variables or alternatives, all I know is that I saw some guy getting destroyed for using them on a separate thread.

Comment: As many have pointed out, there is a better practice, but to address OP I would just shift the board to have the upper left corner be (1,1), and for aesthetics create non-clickable tiles around the full border.

Comment: _"I don't care if you think dynamic variables are inefficient, it's my choice."_ If we see someone pointing a loaded gun at their foot and they say it's their choice to point a loaded gun at their foot, it would be unethical not to mention it's a bad idea. It is the same with using `exec` in the manner that you're using it. It may be your choice, but it's a really bad choice, and it would be unethical for us not to mention that fact. Since you're just now learning to program, you should learn using best practices, not worst practices.

Comment: Just change `x` and `y` start from 1, i.e. 1 <= x <= game.size[0], 1 <= y <= game.size[1].

Comment: Okay this was my post from when I was 14 lmao wtf was I doing

Answer (score 3):

Using dynamic variables is bad practice, and your experience is a good demonstration why.

Variable names cannot have a minus sign in them. The minus sign is interpreted as the arithmetic operator. So `bomb_-1_-1` is interpreted as `bomb_ - 1_ - 1`. The `bomb_` part is understood as a variable name, the `1` as a number, but the underscore following that number is triggering the syntax error.

This also demonstrates that dynamic code is not that great: syntax errors only pop up when certain circumstances are created (like selecting a particular cell).

A quick fix, just to show a work around, is to test first the values of `x` and `y`:

```
if {x} >= 0 and {y} >= 0 and bomb_{x}_{y} == True:
```

You would have to do similar tests for any other place where you create a dynamic reference like that. So also:

```
if {x} >= 1 and {y} >= 1 and bomb_{x-1}_{y-1} == True:
```

...etc.

But this is really patching a terrible design.

Note that even if only one of the variables is negative, you'll evaluate an expression that you did not really intend. You could get this for when only `y == -1`: `bomb_5_-1`. This produces no syntax error, but it evaluates as `bomb_5_` minus `1`. Obviously that is not intended by the algorithm.

Instead of dynamic variables and parsing code at run-time, use lists. They can be nested to have the 2D coverage.

Comment: I understand that you can't have arithmetic operators in variable names, but I did not know there was a way around using dynamic variables. How would I use a list to replace my annoyingly long strings and dynamic variables? Also, if they're so bad, what's their purpose? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: There are many examples of minesweeper implementations in Python. Most use lists. For instance, see how `self.tiles` is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958582/python-logic-in-minesweeper).

Comment: I see this everywhere but don't know what it is. What is __init__, __main__ and self used for?

Comment: `__init__` is a class constructor. Lots of info about that if you search. `main` is just the name of the function that will be executed by a Python interpreter, but that depends on your environment.